# "Module compiled with Swift 4.1.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 4.2 compiler" after updating to Xcode 10.0

Tags: xcode, xcode9, xcode10

I have a SDK named 'MapmyIndiaAPIKit' in my project, after updating to Xcode 10.0, I am getting a error:

> "Module compiled with Swift 4.1.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 4.2 compiler"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46659988/module-compiled-with-swift-4-0-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-3-2-1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Module compiled with Swift 4.1.2 cannot be imported in Swift 4.1.50: Xcode 10 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709377/module-compiled-with-swift-4-1-2-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-4-1-50-xcode-10-er)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Module compiled with Swift 4.1.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 4.2 compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413437/module-compiled-with-swift-4-1-2-cannot-be-imported-by-the-swift-4-2-compiler)

Answer (score -1):

You need to compile the module in Swift 4.2.

In the Xcode project navigator, select the project. Then in the main view select the target for `MapmyIndiaAPIKit` and go to the build settings tab.

In the build settings, do a search for "Swift Language Version" and it should bull up the setting you need to change to 4.2.

A picture is worth a thousand words so...

[image: Setting the Swift Version]

If the API was supplied by a third party in compiled form, you'll need to get them to give you a copy for Swift 4.2. You can't link frameworks and apps that were compiled with different versions of Swift because the ABI is not yet stable.

Comment: i have change swift language to 4.2 but i am not able to see 'MapmyIndiaAPIKit' SDK below TARGETS as show in your image.

Comment: How are you building it then?

Comment: i have edited my question and attached the screenshot for the same